# How to multiarch build images sequentially with docker buildx

Tags: docker, multiarch, buildx

When I want to create multiarch builds with docker, I use the command:

```
docker buildx build --push --platform <list of archs> -t <tag1> -t <tag2> .
```

This works perfectly fine, but seems to be building the images concurrently. In most situations, it may be acceptable, but in some other cases, this seems to be too heavy, requires too much RAM and causes network failures (too many parallel connections).

Is there any way to build the images sequentially?

The only solution I found is to build for each arch separately and then use "docker manifest create" to assemble:

```
docker buildx build --push --platform <arch1> -t <tag-arch1> .
docker buildx build --push --platform <arch2> -t <tag-arch2> .
[...]
docker manifest create ... --amend ...
docker manifest push
```

This may be fine, but it seems that each image is supposed to be pushed to the registry for "docker manifest create" to be able to assemble. This is not very good, as it pollutes the list of images of tags I don't want.

Would it be possible to use "docker manifest create" on local images, without the need to upload each of them separately with a tag to the registry? Is there any better way to simply build the images sequentially?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a `max-parallelism` option in buildkit:

```bash
$ cat buildkitd.toml
[worker.oci]
  max-parallelism = 4

$ docker buildx create --use \
  --name container \
  --driver docker-container \
  --config buildkitd.toml
```

For more details, see: https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/configure/#max-parallelism

The tracking issue for this feature is [buildkit #1131](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1131).

Comment: Thanks. What about building one platform ay a time and assembling, without necessarily pushing?

Comment: @LucaCarlon I haven't played a lot with manifest tool. The docs I saw didn't indicate a push was required, but it makes sense since the push is needed to calculate the digest of the manifest on the registry. I often see repos with platform specific tags, which are just an additional pointer to the same manifest, so no added disk space (maybe a few kb max for the pointer) is used for this.

Comment: May be possible now with the buildkit `max-parallelism` option? https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/configure/#max-parallelism

Comment: @tmm1 indeed, the linked was closed a while back and the feature has been released since this answer was originally provided.